# unable to install intellij IDEA on ubuntu 16.04lts?

Tags: intellij

Two days ago, I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 and
I'm trying to install *intellij IDEA ide* for java coding, it is saying "no such directory found".

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Did you unpack the `tar.gz` file and run the `.sh` in the `bin` directory there?

Comment: Please give us a little more information. Tell us what directory is not found. Tell us exactly how you're trying to install this.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/installing-and-launching.html#d1877703e227 Look here, it's the official guide of 'JetBrains' to install this software on Linux

Comment: user's answer to the question linked to in the preceding comment works in 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to install IntelliJ IDEA Community edition:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-make
umake ide idea
```

To remove IntelliJ IDEA Community edition installed via Ubuntu Make, use this command:

```
umake -r ide idea
```

Comment: i have tried the above commands it is saying  E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-umake
E: Unable to locate package umake
E: Unable to locate package ide
E: Unable to locate package idea

Comment: Sorry. Its ubuntu-make

Comment: it is saying Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ide
E: Unable to locate package idea

Comment: you get that error when running the command umake ide idea? Note you first have to run sudo apt install ubuntu-make. After that is done you run umake ide idea

Comment: thank you sir..
i've installed succesfully and it is really easy installation.

Comment: Great! Please mark the post as answered if it helped you solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You're welcome, here you go, firstly Install required Oracle JDK for Ubuntu, then please follow the following steps:

i-Download Latest IntelliJ IDEA 2016 for Linux: Here IntelliJ IDEA 2016 tar.gz for   Linux.

ii- Either double-Click and Extract IntelliJ Archive into /tmp Or from Shell with a Command-line like:
tar xvzf ~/Downloads/idea*.tar.gz -C /tmp/

iii- sudo su

iv- Set up the root superUser as holder:
chown -R root:root /tmp/idea*

v-Switch the IntelliJ IDEA contents:
mv /tmp/idea* /opt/idea

vi- Making a Symlink into the working Path:
ln -s /opt/idea/bin/idea.sh /usr/local/bin/idea.sh

vii-  End the SuperUser session:
exit

viii-  Launch IDEA from terminal:
idea.sh

Finally perform Initial Customization, enjoy.